# "SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting an error stating: `"SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)" on the line: if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {`

and on

```
data = dbHelper.getTblQuoteNotify("tblQuoteNotify", nCounter);
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` which seems to be the most common resolution to this issue from my research - can anyone else take a look at the code below and let me know what I may have done wrong in this instance?

### Source:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    doTimerTask();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
    data = new Data();
}

 public void doTimerTask(){

        mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    nCounter++;
                                        // update TextView
                                    timer.setText("Notify: " + nCounter);

                                    data = dbHelper.getTblQuoteNotify("tblQuoteNotify", nCounter);
                                    if (data != null) {
                                        data_textview.setText(data.tblQuoteNotify);                                     
                                    }
```

### Logcat:

```
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): Process: com.example.app, PID: 13445
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at com.example.app.data.DBHelper.getTblQuoteNotify(DBHelper.java:67)
05-26 12:01:28.533: E/AndroidRuntime(13445):    at com.example.app.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:69)
```

http://pastebin.com/z8jFk4V0

Comment: Whats the code to open your database? you have the permission but probably you have the incorrect path, you must have something like: private static String DBPATH = "/data/data/com.mypackage.myapp"; so post your code.

Comment: kindly post all the code related to the question.

Comment: Apologies: The full source can be found here: http://pastebin.com/R830dT9w

http://pastebin.com/y8VjYzmY

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by decreasing the frequency of the TimerTask. Attempting to access the database too quickly causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `doTimerTask();` before opening your database. Open database first and then call `doTimerTask(); method` as reviewing your code, I could not run your code, but it seems to be correct but I will suggest that:

1. db file extension should be `.db`  , `.sqlite` etc
2. db file name must be same as asset folder.
3. package name should be same,

Change your code like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //doTimerTask();
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  data_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
  timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
  dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
  try {
    dbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  dbHelper.openDataBase();
  data = new Data();
  doTimerTask(); //**** call doTimerTask here
}
```

I'm not sure that it will help you are not, because you have not posted the code, that we might go through it and fix the bug, anyhow I can suggest you to visit [this](http://androidtutorials60.blogspot.com/2013/03/1.html) and [this](http://tekpot.blogspot.com/2012/08/step-by-step-guide-to-use-existing.html).

Have a look at your DBpath, is it correct? Put your package name correctly.

```
 public final static String DATABASE_PATH ="/data/data/you.package.name/databases/";
```

or check you cursor is properly working, query is correct?

Comment: Apologies: The full source can be found here: http://pastebin.com/R830dT9w

http://pastebin.com/y8VjYzmY

Comment: the url is not opening. you should post your code, if posible.

Comment: it is in the comment above - is it not?

Comment: "url not found response" from browser, do't  know y! but may b this url is not accesable n pak. i have updated answer.

Comment: sorry not working for me. the url responds this "The site you are trying to access contains content that is prohibited for viewership from within Pakistan."

Comment: the problem reside in getTblQuoteNotify() method review that may b you query or cursor is not properly initialize

Comment: I dont see any issues with it

Comment: Try these links... perhaps they will work in your country: http://jqd.org/pastebin?id=11
http://jqd.org/pastebin?id=12

Comment: as my concerns your code is fine,  but you are calling  doTimerTask(); method before opening database, first call opendatabase() method then dotimertask().